# how can i see Trusted People Certificate tab on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, certificate

I need to install a certificate on the trusted people folder once i install it i dont find a tap for that category on Internet Options Certificates IE 7.

What i am missing?

[image]

I have all the other types (Personal, Other People, Trusted Rood Cert ext) exept trusted people and i need to install it on that one and see the key (something that i do on this windows)

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Done, the problem is that i need to see the key but the trusted people is the only one that is not a tab on this page I cant find it. If you Click import you can see the folder to add a certificate to it, but once u add it you cant see it on the main windows (and i dont know were else to look)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. But you can use the [MMC Snap-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788967.aspx).